# Split an Address - TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a field called Address1 in my table Table1.

Here is an example of data in that field -

8 Brick Lane and 11 Balkerne Drive

I want in a query to spit the street and the number but am struggling with how to achieve this.

Any help would be greatful.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the expected result?

Comment: Here is an example of data in that field -

8 Brick Lane and 11 Balkerne Drive or it could be 1c Safe Street

I am writing a query to try and achieve the following from the Address1 field.

In the examples above 8 and 11 would pull back as "HouseNumber".
In the examples above 1c would pull back as "HouseName"
In the examples above Safe Street, Brick Lane and Balkerne Drive would appear in "Street"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
LEFT(Address1, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', Address1)- 1) as HouseNumber, 
SUBSTRING(Address1, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', Address1), LEN(Address1)) as Street
FROM Table1
```

Using PATINDEX to find when HouseName begin, in this way you can separate address. 
This the expected result:

```
HouseNumber Street
8           Brick Lane
11          Balkerne Drive
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

I am asssuming you want to split the number from the text, you can use

```
SELECT Left(Address1,CHARINDEX(' ',Address1,0)-1) as houseNumber,
    Right(Address1,Len(Address1)-CHARINDEX(' ',Address1,0)) as houseStreet
From Table1
```

Comment: Ended up using a combination -   CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',left(Address1,CHARINDEX(' ',Address1,0)-1)) = 0 
  THEN left(Address1,CHARINDEX(' ',Address1,0)-1) ELSE NULL END AS BuildingNumber,
  CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',left(Address1,CHARINDEX(' ',Address1,0)-1)) > 0 
  THEN left(Address1,CHARINDEX(' ',Address1,0)-1) ELSE NULL END AS BuildingName,
    Right(Address1,Len(Address1)-CHARINDEX(' ',Address1,0)) AS Street,